# How to remove IPv6 values belongs for country and city?

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

> Currently I'm converting IPv4 Address to IPv4 Number for finding country  and city and then I'll save the other details in my database.

```
Example: IPv4 (172.16.254.1)
```

> 172 - Country
>   16  - city
>   254 - Host
>   1   - user
>
> I'll save 254.1 in my DB .
>
> some one please explain what is city and state from below address

`IPv6 (2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334)`

Comment: What you really want?

Comment: i want to know which is country value in IPV6

Comment: why you tag this question as `sql` , `database` i think this question is about networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses, whether IPv4 or IPv6, don't work the way you seem to think.  An IPv4 address does have four octets, but they are NOT Country.City.Host.User!  An IP address is really two parts: Network and Host.

For IPv4, the exact number of bits in each part varies by the mask, but they add up to 32 bits.

IPv6 is a little different since the host part is, except in a few corner cases, always 64 bits.  The entire address is 128 bits.

Nothing in the RFCs defines location.